# Using three.js in html to export a 3d model from its URL

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I've been trying to export a model from its URL (substituted with example.com) here. I am new to javascript and html, and most of this was generated by an AI, and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <p>First test line</p>
      <p>Second test line</p>
      <p>Third test line</p>
      <p>Fourth test line</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports":
      {
        "three": "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js",
        "three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader": "/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js"
      }
    }
  <script type="module">
    import * as THREE from 'three'
    import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
    //import { OBJLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/three/addons/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
    //import { OBJLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/build/OBJLoader.js';
    // Define the model URL
    var modelUrl = "https://example.com/mymodel";
    // Create a new Three.js scene
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create a new Three.js OBJ loader
    var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    // Load the model into the scene
    loader.load(modelUrl, function (object) {
        scene.add(object);
    });

    // Function to export the model to a file
    function exportModel() {
      var exporter = new THREE.OBJExporter();
      var modelString = exporter.parse( scene );
      var file = new Blob([modelString], {type: "text/plain"});
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "model.obj";
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      setTimeout(function() {
          document.body.removeChild(a);
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
      }, 0); 
    }
    document.getElementById("exportbutton").addEventListener("click",exportModel);
  </script>
  <button id="exportbutton">Export Model</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The code I was trying to use to get the URL (which also doesn't work, so I had to do it manually) is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    // Define the website URL
    var websiteUrl = "https://example.com";

    // Use the Fetch API to retrieve the website's HTML content
    fetch(websiteUrl)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        // Use regular expressions to search for 3D model URLs in the HTML content
        var regex = /https?:\/\/[^\s]+\.(obj|stl|gltf|glb|fbx)/gi;
        var matches = data.match(regex);
        if (matches) {
          // save the URLs of the 3D models to a text file
          var textFile = null;
          var makeTextFile = function (text) {
            var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
            if (textFile !== null) {
              window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
            }
            textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
            return textFile;
          };
          var create = document.getElementById('create');
          create.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
            link.href = makeTextFile(matches.join('\n'));
            link.style.display = 'block';
          }, false);
        } else {
          console.log("No 3D models found on the website.");
        }
      });
  </script>
  <button id="create">Download URLs</button>
  <a download="3D_models_URLs.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display:none;"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Among other errors, I have got this error:
JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 9 column 3 of the JSON data

What do I need to do?

Comment: Just to verify if I understand your problem. You want to fetch a 3D model from a remote URL, and then load it into three.js? If that's the case, what is the format of your 3D model (fbx, stl, obj, blend, gltf - suggested, something else)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway Nepttune is trying to crawl the website `example.com`, then extract any `.gltf|.obj|.fbx` file from it, load it into Three.js, then save it as an `.obj` into their hard-drive. I'm voting to close this question because it's asking too many things at once.

Comment: @Marquizzo Right, so my initial understanding was not far off. Thanks.

Comment: your sending the scene to the exporter, shouldn't you be sending it the model? But I am voting to close as it sounds like you are trying to scrape models that might otherwise need to be paid for.

Comment: @2pha sorry I don't really know anything about html, or javascript (I'm more usd to working in C# or python), so I don't really know what most of the program means. I guess this question will be taken down so I'll just let this just not work and abandon it. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Do you want to save the 3d model locally from a remote link? If so, you don't need three.js nor Javascript for that. You can work with C# or python to achieve what you need.

Comment: @FiddlingAway Oh yes of course! Thank you! I can't remember why now, but I thought it could only be done in HTML using javascript and three.js. I will attempt to do it in python since I don't have or know how to use a c# environment that isn't unity, which isn't really designed for this sort of thing.